# Concatenating strings from registers and printing them

Tags: assembly, masm, cpuid

I am trying to call cpuid and print output from EBX, ECX and EDX to console, but it prints empty line instead

here is my code:

```
.586 

.model flat,stdcall 

option casemap:none 

include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib  

.data
.data?
mybuffer byte 100 dup(?)

.code 
start: 

mov      eax, 0
cpuid

invoke   lstrcpy, addr mybuffer, ebx   
invoke   lstrcat, addr mybuffer, ecx
invoke   lstrcat, addr mybuffer, edx

invoke   GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
invoke   WriteConsole, eax, addr mybuffer, sizeof mybuffer, NULL, NULL

invoke   ExitProcess, 0

end start
```

Comment: strcpy and strcat expect pointers but you really have the characters in the registers. You can just do `mov mybuffer, ebx; mov mybuffer+4, ecx; mov mybuffer+8, edx` and that should work. Use `12` instead of `sizeof mybuffer` for printing.

Comment: I did as you said, but got an "invalid instruction operands" error at every `mov` line. Is mybuffer declaration correct?

Comment: Maybe try changing it to `dword` no idea about `masm`. Also try using brackets such as `mov [mybuffer+4], ecx` or even `mov dword ptr [mybuffer+4], ecx`.

Comment: Thanks, dword made it work.