# Joining strings from registers and printing them (CPUID)

Tags: string, assembly, x86, nasm, cpuid

Starting to learn NASM assembly, I was looking at some assembly questions here in Stack Overflow and found this one here:
[Concatenating strings from registers and printing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165150/concatenating-strings-from-registers-and-printing-them)

> I believe that this question is not duplicated because I am trying to
>   replicate the code in NASM and also things were not very clear in the
>   other question.

I decided to **replicate this code in NASM**, but I did not quite understand the MASM code in question.
I learned about `CPUID` and did some testing programs.

In order, I'd like to know how we can concatenate registers and then print them on the screen USING NASM.

I want to print 'ebx' + 'edx' + 'ecx' because this is how the `CPUID` output is organized by [what I see in GDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI1OA.png).

I called `CPUID` with `eax=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"String" is not a very precise term. The Vendor Identification String of CPUID/EAX=0 contains only 12 ASCII characters, packed into 3 DWORD registers. There is no termination character like in C nor a length information like in PASCAL. But it's always the same registers and it's always 3*4=12 bytes. This is ideal for the write-syscall:

```
section .bss

    buff resb 12

section .text
global _start

_start:

    mov eax, 0
    cpuid

    mov dword [buff+0], ebx     ; Fill the first four bytes
    mov dword [buff+4], edx     ; Fill the second four bytes
    mov dword [buff+8], ecx     ; Fill the third four bytes


    mov eax, 4                  ; SYSCALL write
    mov ebx, 1                  ; File descriptor = STDOUT
    mov ecx, buff               ; Pointer to ASCII string
    mov edx, 12                 ; Count of bytes to send
    int 0x80                    ; Call Linux kernel

    mov eax, 1                  ; SYSCALL exit
    mov ebx, 0                  ; Exit Code
    int 80h                     ; Call Linux kernel
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you tell me more about why use the .bss session to store this buffer variable.

Comment: @PySnake: Two reasons: 1) The buffer is uninitialized and 2) it looks awful to define an array of 12 empty bytes in the .data section. In the executable there are only informations about the length of the BSS section, no values like DATA or TEXT. The whole segment is built at program startup.